# Unexpected UL error / List problems Epson HX-20

Tags: data-preservation, epson

I have an Epson HX-20 which has been in storage since I last used it in 2013.

To my surprise the program I wrote back then is still stored in RAM, and by LISTing it (and checking it against the external backup I made), I can verify that it is in place.

However, when I run the program if ever it comes across a GOSUB statement, it stops with error UL (Undefined Line Number).

If I LIST the whole program, I can see the line numbers in question. However if I type LIST {line number} I get a blank output.

Can anyone explain what has probably happened, and what I could do to recover things in place?

I am aware that I could type the whole program in again, or try to transfer it from backup - the first being time consuming and the second risky as if anything goes wrong I will delete the program anyway. I'm really more interested in understanding what has happened that simply restoring the program.

Comment: Very probably, there is two types of "line number chains" that thread through the program (1) the line numbers in the ASCII text (2) some BASIC internal pointers linking to GOSUB/GOTO targets, and apparently the second sort is lost. If you would save and re-load from mass storage, chances are this would be re-generated.

Comment: Ok - just discovered the internal tape recorder is not working any more, so I'd have to try with external tape. Thanks for the tip. Btw wouldn't your comment be an answer?

Comment: Too much of a guess to be a real answer, I'm afraid. I don't have an HX-20.

Comment: Perhaps try https://frigolit.net/projects/hxemu/ .  Read the **About me** bit.

Answer (score 1):

First, how did you store prog in RAMFILE, which is intended for storing formatted data?

Secondly, if you don't have a tape recorder, you can connect to main PC microphone input and record (SAVE) prog to a .WAV file. You can then LOAD back onto HX. I've had excellent results doing this with my HX and a laptop.

Comment: Welcome to *Retrocomputing!*  If you have a question, please post it as its own question, not as the answer to another question.

Comment: @DrSheldon, that doesn’t look like a “question” but more like a request for clarification. Geoff questions part of the premise of the question (“stored in ramfile”) which he must think cannot be true. It’s probably an inconsequential misstatement by the original poster. He then suggest a fix. Outside of some grammar tweaks, I think the form of the answer is fine (but I can’t judge on its substance).

Comment: I might be using the wrong terminology, but I just meant the program was still held in RAM, or apparently so.

Comment: OK, there is a specific facility within the HX-20 BASIC called RAMFILE, and I wondered just what you were meaning re storing BASIC code there.   Oh, if you've still got the problem, another thing you might try is to RENUM the prog, which might restore the links referred to in earlier comment.   In any case, prob a good idea to SAVE the prog first, unless you've got the means to re-enter it all.